# Gui.Window ContextClick

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to add an Event.ContextClick to a Gui.Window in a Unity Editor script?

The following is my context menu method that I've tried calling from both **OnGUI()** and my window's **WindowFunction** (call sites denoted below as "**site: no luck**").  I have not been able to get the "Success" message to show up unless I'm right clicking directly in the main editor window. If I right click in any of the Gui.Windows I have created, the ContextClick event doesn't show up.

```
void OnStateContextMenu(){
    Event evt = Event.current;

    // Ignore anything but contextclicks
    if(evt.type != EventType.ContextClick)return;

    Debug.Log("Success");

    // Add generic menu at context point
    GenericMenu menu = new GenericMenu();
    menu.AddItem (new GUIContent ("AddState"),false,AddState,evt.mousePosition);
    menu.ShowAsContext ();
    evt.Use();
}
```

And the call site(s):

```
void doWindow(int id){
    // OnStateContextMenu(); //site1: no luck
    GUI.DragWindow();
}

void OnGUI(){
    OnStateContextMenu(); //site2: no luck here either
    BeginWindows();
    wndRect = GUI.Window(0,wndRect,doWindow,"StateWnd");   
    EndWindows();
}
```

**Update**

For reference, green area responds to right-click, red area does not.  But I want it to. The right-click menu I've created has specific actions I only want visible if the mouse cursor right clicks inside one of my windows, the 'Hello' in the image.  Note:  Ignore the button, right click doesn't work anywhere inside that window.

[image]

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do. You want to run something the moment a specific part of the context is clicked or just when the context is clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not directly answer your question but should be able to help

You are trying to achieve a rightclick function inside your red box( as shown in picute )
I had a sort alike question a while back but it was not for a rightclick but for a mouseover
so i figured this might be able to help you

```
string mouseover;  // first of i created a new string

 if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100,100,200,200),new GUIContent("Load game", "MouseOverOnButton0") ,menutexture ))
  {
     //added a mousoveronbutton command to my GUIcontent
      executestuff();
  }

     buttoncheck();       

}
        void buttoncheck()
        {
                mouseover = GUI.tooltip;
                if(mouseover == "MouseOverOnButton0")
                {
                        GUI.Box(new Rect(380,45,235,25),"Not a implemented function as of yet ");

                }

        }
```

this code made a new gui box the moment the mouse hitted the box.

If you created the *hello* in a seperate box you could use this

```
if(mouseover == hello)
{
  if(rightclick == true)
  { 
    execute the stuff you want 
  }

}
```

or something like that. Hope this helps a bit atleast

***UPDATE***

To obtain the rightclick event you will have to use the

if(Event.current.button == 1 && Event.current.isMouse)

You have to place this in the OnGUI to work properly

this way you first trigger the in box part, then check for a right click and execute the stuff you want.

Comment: I see what you're suggesting, and it's a good thought for OnMouseOver-like behavior, but the "rightclick == true" is where I'm hung up.  Editor scripts only react to mouseinput via Events.  And no event triggers a "rightclick" so even if I know I'm over a Gui.Window, nothing tells me the right mouse button is down.

Comment: @Jerdak I made a update for you this time. With this i think you will be able to notice the right click and execute a event if you want.

Comment: Your answer lead me to a working solution and I'll accept if you change a couple of things.  First off, Input [does not work](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15067/input-in-editor-scripts.html) in the Editor, if(Event.current.button == 1 && Event.current.isMouse ) will get the right-click.  Second, Event.current must be called from inside OnGUI(), inside of Update() it fails.